# Meteor import from outside the `/imports` directory

Tags: meteor

I have files in a `/models/` directory off the root of the Meteor application. That directory is in `.meteorignore` so it’s not automatically loaded.

I can’t do `import SomeModule from '/models/some-module.js'` from a file in the `/imports/` directory. In `some-module.js`, the error says that the export or import (at the top of the `some-module.js` file) is an error.

```
export default function () {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at /Users/sunnyhirai/Projects/kb/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:332:30
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/sunnyhirai/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.4_2.1glyugb.deq2++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
at /Users/sunnyhirai/Projects/kb/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:158:5
at /Users/sunnyhirai/Projects/kb/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:388:5
at Function.run (/Users/sunnyhirai/Projects/kb/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
at /Users/sunnyhirai/Projects/kb/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:387:11
```

In other words it is treating `/models/` directory different than `/imports/` directory. The same file in the `/imports/` directory will import fine.

Please, if anybody knows how to fix this without moving all the files into `/imports/` I would be grateful.

Comment: It shouldn't matter about the location. Are you importing on the server or the client?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
import {SomeModule}from '/models/some-module.js'
```